# JavaScript based WebSocket Client Not Receiving any Output to Browser Console using Spring Reactor Web Sockets

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, websocket, project-reactor

I was following along a tutorial for setting up web sockets that used Pivotal's Reactor Framework API.

The example would entail, after running the Spring Boot Reactive Microservice, to launching the Google Chrome web browser and opening up a specific URL (with a port) and then clicking on View / Source and then clicking on Console.

This should have produced a log message to Google Chrome's Console's stdout.

However, nothing is outputted...

---

Project structure:

```
rswebsockets
│
├── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradlew
├── gradlew.bat
├── settings.gradle
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── com
    │   │       └── reactive
    │   │           ├── RsWebSocketsApplication.java
    │   │           ├── config
    │   │           │   └── WebSocketConfig.java
    │   │           ├── model
    │   │           │   ├── GreetingRequest.java
    │   │           │   └── GreetingResponse.java
    │   │           └── service
    │   │               └── GreetingService.java
    │   └── resources
    │       ├── application.properties
    │       └── static
    │           └── ws.html
    └── test
        └── java
            └── com
                └── reactive
                    └── RsWebSocketsApplicationTests.java
```

---

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.reactive'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '14'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

---

Codebase:

rswebsockets/src/main/java/com/reactive/RsWebSocketsApplication.java:

```
package com.reactive;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class RsWebSocketsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RsWebSocketsApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

rswebsockets/src/main/java/com/reactive/config/WebSocketConfig.java:

```
package com.reactive.config;

import com.reactive.model.GreetingRequest;
import com.reactive.model.GreetingResponse;
import com.reactive.service.GreetingService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketHandler;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.WebSocketMessage;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.server.support.WebSocketHandlerAdapter;

import java.util.Map;

public class WebSocketConfig {

    @Bean
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping(WebSocketHandler wsh) {
        return new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(Map.of("/ws/greetings", wsh), 10);
    }

    @Bean
    WebSocketHandler webSocketHandler(GreetingService greetingService) {
        return session -> {
           var receive = session
                            .receive()
                            .map(WebSocketMessage::getPayloadAsText)
                            .map(GreetingRequest::new)
                            .flatMap(greetingService::greet)
                            .map(GreetingResponse::getMessage)
                            .map(session::textMessage);
           return session.send(receive);
        };
    }

    @Bean
    WebSocketHandlerAdapter webSockerHandlerAdapter() {
        return new WebSocketHandlerAdapter();
    }
}
```

---

rswebsockets/src/main/java/com/reactive/model/GreetingRequest.java:

```
package com.reactive.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GreetingRequest {

    String name;

}
```

---

rswebsockets/src/main/java/com/reactive/model/GreetingResponse.java:

```
package com.reactive.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class GreetingResponse {

    String message;

}
```

---

rswebsockets/src/main/java/com/reactive/service/GreetingService.java:

```
package com.reactive.service;

import com.reactive.model.GreetingRequest;
import com.reactive.model.GreetingResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

@Service
public class GreetingService {

    public Flux<GreetingResponse> greet(GreetingRequest request) {
        return Flux.fromStream(
                Stream.generate(() -> new GreetingResponse("Hello " + request.getName() + " @ " + Instant.now())))
                      .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1));

    }
}
```

---

rswebsockets/src/main/resources/static/ws.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
        var ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080/ws/greetings')
        ws.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
            ws.send('Livelessons Fans')
        });
        ws.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
            console.log(e.data);
        });

    })
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

After running the microservice (nothing breaks on startup) using:

```
gradle bootRun
```

output:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-05-06 14:46:41.393  INFO 39122 --- [           main] com.reactive.RsWebSocketsApplication     : Starting RsWebSocketsApplication on Porsche959.local with PID 39122 (/Users/pnwlover/rswebsockets/build/classes/java/main started by pnwlover in /Users/pnwlover/rswebsockets)
2020-05-06 14:46:41.395  INFO 39122 --- [           main] com.reactive.RsWebSocketsApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-06 14:46:42.126  INFO 39122 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.netty.NettyWebServer  : Netty started on port(s): 8080
2020-05-06 14:46:42.129  INFO 39122 --- [           main] com.reactive.RsWebSocketsApplication     : Started RsWebSocketsApplication in 0.941 seconds (JVM running for 1.579)
```

---

Opened up Google Chrome and launched the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/ws.html
```

---

Opened up Google Chrome Developer Tools by going to view page source and then clicking on the Console tab:

[image: Google Chrome Console Tab]

---

Google Chome Developer Tools - Sources Tab:

[image: Google Chome Developer Tools Sources Tab]

---

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Comment: Try `return new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping(Map.of("/ws/greetings", wsh), Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);` It's probably running after the controller code, so returns 404 as no controller is present with  URI of `/ws/greetings`.

Comment: @123 - It doesn't still work... For some reason, line 5 inside ```ws.html``` throws an HTTP 404 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by placing the `@Configuration` above the WebSocketConfig class:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSocketConfig { 

    // Methods omitted for brevity.
}
```

---

[image]